# Tell Ruby Program to Wait some amount of time

Tags: ruby, sleep

How do you tell a Ruby program to wait an arbitrary amount of time before moving on to the next line of code?

Answer (score 795, accepted):

Like this:

```
sleep(num_secs)
```

The `num_secs` value can be an integer or float.

Also, if you're writing this within a Rails app, or have included the ActiveSupport library in your project, you can construct longer intervals using the following convenience syntax:

```
sleep(4.minutes)
# or, even longer...
sleep(2.hours); sleep(3.days) # etc., etc.
# or shorter
sleep(0.5) # half a second
```

Answer (score 142):

Use [sleep](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep) like so:

```
sleep 2
```

That'll sleep for 2 seconds.

Be careful to give an argument. If you just run `sleep`, the process will sleep forever. (This is useful when you want a thread to sleep until it's woken.)

Comment: Wait, will it sleep forever, or until it's "woken"? What does "woken" even mean?

Comment: @anthropomorphic It's referring to when another thread calls Thread#run.

Comment: Actually, when another thread calls Thread#wakeup, I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

I find `until` very useful with sleep. example:

```
> time = Time.now
> sleep 2.seconds until Time.now > time + 10.seconds # breaks when true
> # or
> sleep 2 and puts 'still sleeping' until Time.now > time + 10
> # or
> sleep 1.seconds until !req.loading # suggested by ohsully
```

Comment: This is the same thing as `sleep(10.seconds)`

Comment: Yeah, here it is the same because it uses the same input (time) as offered by sleep. I wanted to highlight how `until` can be used to sleep until any condition is achieved (also love the how natural the syntax feels)

Comment: This makes my head hurt. Can you provide a different example than this to showcase the value of using `until` here instead of just `sleep(10.seconds)`?

Comment: Suppose you wanted to block until a request returns: `sleep 1.seconds until !req.loading`

Comment: This is not exactly the same thing as sleep(10). The kernel may wake the thread early. So if you *must* sleep for at least 10 seconds, you need a construct like this.  See https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep

Comment: @MZB you are right. But in case you want to call `Thread#run` from another thread, you might just place that condition in until which will give more ownership to the sleeping thread. Might be totally wrong here

Answer (score 8):

Like this

`sleep(no_of_seconds)`

Or you may pass other possible arguments like:

`sleep(5.seconds)`

`sleep(5.minutes)`

`sleep(5.hours)`

`sleep(5.days)`

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of seconds/minutes/hours, which are rails methods. Note that implicit returns aren't needed, but they look cleaner, so I prefer them. I'm not sure Rails even has .days or if it goes further, but these are the ones I need.

```rb
class Integer
   def seconds
      return self
   end
   def minutes
      return self * 60
   end
   def hours
      return self * 3600
   end
   def days
      return self * 86400
   end
end
```

After this, you can do:
`sleep 5.seconds` to sleep for 5 seconds. You can do `sleep 5.minutes` to sleep for 5 min. You can do `sleep 5.hours` to sleep for 5 hours. And finally, you can do `sleep 5.days` to sleep for 5 days... You can add any method that return the value of self * (amount of seconds in that timeframe). 
As an exercise, try implementing it for months!

Answer (score 0):

`sleep 6` will sleep for 6 seconds. For a longer duration, you can also use `sleep(6.minutes)` or `sleep(6.hours)`.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes on this, but it could be that `minutes()` and `hours()` are methods on numerics added by Ruby on Rails - so not standard available in Ruby - in the ActiveSupport::Duration class. They're quite convenient though.

Comment: I think the primary reason for downvotes is that @vijaya_chowdary basically reposted the voted correct answer 8 years later. I would consider it is strange at the least...

Comment: I downvoted for exactly that. It's not standard ruby.

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of using `sleep` with `sidekiq`

```rb
require 'sidekiq'

class PlainOldRuby
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(how_hard="super hard", how_long=10)
    sleep how_long
    puts "Workin' #{how_hard}"
  end
end
```

sleep for 10 seconds and print out `"Working super hard"` .

Comment: This is writing (sin²+cos²) instead of 1.